# Highlight or emphatize replies from high ranked users

Tags: feature-request, top-users, highlighting

What happens if there's an answer with a lot of votes, and even marked as accepted, but a user find a better solution? maybe nobody get it.
I think that top users replies should be highlighted in some way, because we know that replies from advanced developers always are good.

Comment: Well, they are highlighted in a way — every post shows the user reputation.

Comment: As a 5-digit rep user I feel that would put undue pressure on me.  Some of my answers aren't always good and I like how the current system corrects me.

Comment: @Bavarious: The rep of a user isn't visible until you scroll to the end of a post, and users with rep that displays as "11.1k" might not immediately be read as a 5-digit number.

Comment: and what about adding a new tab for the order of replies? currently we have "active", "oldest", "votes", what about adding "reputation" or something like that?

Answer (score 14):

It is a slippery slope.

To quote Orwell:

> ALL ANIMALS ARE EQUAL, BUT SOME ANIMALS ARE MORE EQUAL THAN OTHERS.

At Stack Overflow, we believe that information is king, great information may come from 1 rep users or 10k users.

Comment: +1 great citation. No wonder, you have a lot of rep ;)

Comment: +1 because you have lots of reps :P

Comment: @YOU See? Enrique was right after all...

Comment: Yup. Judge the post, not the poster. Everytime.

Comment: I want to clarify my request (my english is not good sorry). Your quote is totally false @waffles, you know that, and it's the best of the life that we are noe equal, anyone!. You are choosing by reputation everyday @waffles! when you buy a cellphone you see the trademark and even where is made, when you bought a book you read about the author, when you hire someone you ask him for a CV, etc. It's not warrany, but it's a good point of reference. I trust more in code and help from advanced users than newbies, don't you?

Answer (score 3):

An *argumentum ad hominem* fallacy right there.

The fact that an answer comes from a highly ranked user does not mean is the best answer. The community will rank the answers based on the quality, so if an answer gets a lot of votes it's probably because it's a good answer, regardless of the rep of the person that answered. If you believe that another answer is better, then upvote it, and even leave a comment in the highest voted one stating why you think it's not the best.